# Is Paramahansa the vahana to the promised land?

Tags: book-recommendation, om

The great " Mystical  Spirit Swan " known as Paramahansa is revered by Hindus, and is believed to be the vehicle to the promised land for the individuals Spirit. Is he composed of Swarupas ? If so what are they and where are these vibrations activated on Paramahansa ?

Comment: Your questions are mostly assumptions, not questions. They have no real basis and solid grounding. Paramhansa is not a swan, rather it is metaphorically representing one, as in a person has reached that stage. And you don't need to be a Paramhansa to be a siddha. Siddhis are activated merely by practicing fruitful yoga.

Comment: And there is no Promised Land concept. Although you can say that the final destination Brahman is somewhat a promised land of sorts.

Answer (score 6):

Paramhamsa is actually the name of a class of ascetics.

Other classes are Kuticaka, Bahudaka, Hamsa etc. A Paramhamsa is considered as the one who have spiritually evolved the most among these classes.

Several references to them can be found in the minor Upanishads and other scriptures.

Here is one such reference from the Narada Parivrajaka Upanishad (which talks a lot about Sannyasis and Sannyasa):

> "A bath is ordained three times a day for Kutlcakas, twice a day for
>   Bahudakas, and once a day for Hamsas. **A mental bath is ordained for
>   Paramahamsas**, a bath with ashes for Turiyatitas, and a wind bath for
>   Avadhutas. A vertical mark on the forehead is ordained for Kutlcakas,
>   a triple horizontal mark for Bahudakas, both a vertical and a triple
>   horizontal mark for Hamsas [NpU 174, n. 58], **the smearing with ashes
>   for Paramahamsas**, a spot with sandal paste for Turiyatitas, but none
>   at all for Avadhutas. Kutlcakas are required to shave every season,
>   and Bahudakas every other season.100 [204] **Hamsas and Paramahamsas are
>   not required to shave, but if they do, they shave every six months**.101
>   Turiyatitas and Avadhutas do not shave at all. "Kutlcakas may eat a
>   full meal given by one person. Bahudakas beg their food in the manner
>   of a bee [NpU 174, n. 57]. **Hamsas and Paramahamsas use their hands as
>   begging bowls,** while Turiyatitas use their mouths like cows and
>   Avadhutas obtain their food in the manner of a python [NpU 175, nn.
>   61-62]. "Two garments are prescribed for Kutlcakas, a single garment
>   for Bahudakas, and a rag for Hamsas. **Paramahamsas may go naked or wear
>   a single loincloth.** Turiyatitas and Avadhutas are clad as they were at
>   birth. An antelope skin is prescribed for Hamsas and Paramahamsas, but
>   not for others. "Divine worship is ordained for Kutlcakas and
>   Bahudakas, mental worship for Hamsas and Paramahamsas, [205] and the
>   so'ham meditation [NpU 191, n. 87] for Turiyatitas and Avadhutas.
>   Kutlcakas and Bahudakas are qualified to mutter mantras, **while Hamsas
>   and Paramahamsas are qualified to meditate.** The qualification of
>   Turiyatltas and Avadhutas, however, does not extend to anything that
>   involves another.102 Turiyatitas and Avadhutas, as well as
>   Paramahamsas, are qualified to teach the Great Sayings

Yet another reference from another minor Upanishad called the Bhikshuka Upanishad:

> **[233] There are four types of mendicants who aspire to liberation: Kuticakas, Bahudakas, Hamsas, and Paramahamsa**s [AsU 100, n. 8].
>   Kuticakas are people such as Gautama, Bharadvaja, Yajnavalkya, and
>   Vasistha, who, eating eight mouthfuls,1 seek only liberation by the
>   yogic path. [234] Bahudakas are those who carry a triple staff and a
>   water pot; who wear a topknot, a sacrificial string, and an ochre
>   garment; -who, avoiding honey and meat, beg eight mouthfuls of food
>   from the house of a Brahmin seer; and who seek only liberation by the
>   yogic path. Hamsas are those who do not stay more than one night in a
>   village, five nights in a town, and seven nights in a sacred place;
>   who consume cow's urine and dung;2 who are always given to the lunar
>   fast [AsU 101, n. 9]; and who seek only liberation by the yogic path.
>   Paramahamsas3 are [235] men such as Samvartaka, Aruni, Svetaketu,
>   Jadabharata, Dattatreya, Suka, Vamadeva, and Haritaka, who, eating
>   eight mouthfuls, seek only liberation by the yogic path. They live at
>   the foot of trees, or in deserted houses, or in cemeteries. They
>   either wear a garment or go naked.

And, no there is no swan that will take one to "that land" :). It's not that easy and there's no shortcut.

But, Hamsa and Paramahamsa both these words are also used to refer to the supreme self (Paramatama). Refer to the the Hamsa Mantra for example.

**EDIT**

I'm responding to your following comment:

> WHAT no swan, the most elegant of birds that I am the tail of does
>   not exist, now Rickross you are messing with my brain . Hehehe. Maha
>   Hamsa who is the accumulated whole of all Jivatmans, the vahana of
>   Saraswati and Brahma, depicted in millions of paintings, pictures and
>   sculptures, are you really saying that Hamsa is not real ? What to
>   believe who to believe.

You are right with couple of things you have said here. Swan is indeed considered as the best among birds. In scriptures we find a lot of verses saying " Just like Ganga is among rivers, cow among all animals, swan among the birds, ... ".

And, it is also true that Lord Brahma's mount is a swan.

One of the Gayatri Mantras for Lord Brahma is the following:

> Om chaturmukhaye vidmahe **hamsarudhaye** dhimahi tanno brahma
>   prachodayath ||

Here, the word **Hamsarudhaye** means the one who rides on the Hamsa or a swan.

But, in scriptures, when we find the word Paramhamsa it mostly refers to a particular kind of ascetic as already mentioned above.

Sometimes, the word can also refer to the Supreme Self (Paramatma). For e.g. in case of the Hamsa Mantra.

One Gayatri Mantra for Parambrahma is the following:

> Om hamsa hamsaya vidmahe **param hamsaya dhimahi** tanno hamsa
>   prachodayath ||

So, here Hamsa, Paramhamsa are referring to the Supreme Self.

So, you are not absolutely wrong but that idea about the swan is not entirely correct too. :)

Comment: WHAT no swan, the most elegant of birds that I am the tail of does not exist, now Rickross you are messing with my brain . Hehehe. Maha Hamsa who is the accumulated whole of all Jivatmans, the vahana of Saraswati and Brahma,  depicted in millions of paintings, pictures and sculptures, are you really saying that Hamsa is not real ? What to believe who to believe.

Comment: Yes Hamsa is the vahana of Brahma alright but the Paramhamsa term is not at all used to denote that bird. It is used to denote a group of Sannyasi. It can also refer to the highest self. I will update the answer regarding this. @FrankHestermann

Comment: @FrankHestermann see my revised answer.

Comment: @FrankHestermann That swan u are talking about belongs to Lord Brahma, only he will ride it we can't :D

Comment: your research is great, is there anything out there about the Swarupas - parts  of the Hamsa and the jnanas of the siddhis ?

Comment: I am not that clear on that part. If u can give some links that will help me understand the concept better. Probably then i can further update my answer with my response. @FrankHestermann

Comment: I read somewhere that not unlike the chakras there was a different vibrations for the head, neck, body tail :- A. U. M. Which are likened to the key to ignite the vahana,.