# Who are Paramahamsa-Sanyasis?

Tags: sanyasi

We know Who are Sannyasins. I heard words like 'Dasanama Sanyasa, Paramahamsa Sanyas, Paramahamsa parivraja Sanyasa and the like. I would like to the types and the disciplines if any.

Comment: Hamsa, Paramhamsa, Turiatita etc are various types of Sannyasis .. You can see this: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/28620/4732

Comment: yes, Paramhansa sannyasins properly explained by Rickross in that answer. There are bahudaka, kutichaka, hamsa and paramahamsa sannyasins